# How to create a new repo on gitlab from terminal on local?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am aware and even use this approach to create new repository on github.com, offcourse it uses github.com login creditentials, I am looking forward for a similar approach to create a remote repo on gitlab from terminal, I need to implement this to have a  controlled developer workflow.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new repository

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:Username/Project.git
cd Project
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "add README"
git push -u origin master
```

Existing folder

```
cd existing_folder
git init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:Username/Project.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: what is the difference between `remote add origin` and `remote set-url` ?

Comment: set-url is used to update for existing repo's origin.

Comment: OP asked for creating a repo from the terminal, you're cloning an available repository and pushing to it.

Comment: If your company Prefixes the URL like "git.company.com", the corresponding command should be `git remote add origin git@git.company.com:Username/Project.git`. Also mind the : in front of username